# How to use FluentDesignForm with RibbonControl?

Tags: winforms, devexpress, ribbon-control, fluent-design

I want to use `FluentDesignForm` with `RibbonControl` from DevExpress to realize effect illustrated in Image1, but what I actually get is Image2. The problem is that the min/max/close buttons at right top corner of FluentDesignForm are missing and I cannot move the form by dragging its title bar. Is it possible to realize the effect I want?
Here is Image1:
[image: Image1]
and Image2:
[image: Image2]

Answer (score 1):

DevExpress did not use the `FluentDesignForm` for this. Their form is a `RibbonForm`. The inheritance tree looks like this:

```
DevExpress.XtraGrid.Demos.frmMain
> DevExpress.DXperience.Demos.RibbonMainForm
> DevExpress.XtraBars.Ribbon.RibbonForm
> DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraForm
> DevExpress.XtraEditors.MouseWheelContainerForm
> DevExpress.XtraEditors.DForm
> System.Windows.Forms.Form
```

The `RibbonForm` has no control box and is supposed to be used with a `RibbonControl` handling this.

On the left side, they use a custom control derived from the `AccordionControl`:

```
DevExpress.DXperience.Demos.NavigationControl
> DevExpress.XtraBars.Navigation.AccordionControl
> DevExpress.XtraEditors.BaseStyleControl
> DevExpress.XtraEditors.BaseControl
> DevExpress.Utils.Controls.ControlBase
> System.Windows.Forms.Control
```

Their trick is to put their `NavigationControl` (aka `AccordionControl`) directly onto the `RibbonForm` and override the accordion's method `GetUseDirectCompositionStyle()` to return `true` (without checking for DirectX and stuff).